# Getting switch statement to work using a json value

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I created a switch statement that looks for a value of a JSON object and based on that value supplies data to the console. However it is not working. Can someone tell me what im missing?

```
.controller('GeoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = "";
    $http.get('http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?country=usa&state=arizona&city=phoenix&key=PxJe9btQYWReyQFAm')
      .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
        console.log('data success');
        console.log(data); // for browser console
        $scope.result = data; // for UI
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
        console.log('data error');
      })
      .then(function(result){
        things = result.data;
          val = $(things.data.current.pollution.aqius);
          console.log(val);
          var level;
          var health;
          var sport;
          switch (true) {
              case (val < 50):
                  level = "Good";
                  health = "Air quality is considered satisfactory, and air pollution poses little or no risk";
                  sport = "Perfect day to play!";
                  break;
              case (51 <= val && val < 100):
                  level = "Moderate";
                  health = "Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion.";
                  break;
              case (101 <= val && val < 150):
                  level = "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups";
                  health = "Members of sensitive groups may experience health effects. The general public is not likely to be affected.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid prolonged outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion";
                  break;
              case (151 <= val && val < 200):
                  level = "Unhealthy";
                  health = "Unhealthy Everyone may begin to experience health effects; members of sensitive groups may experience more serious health effects";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid prolonged outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion";
                  break;
              case (201 <= val && val < 300):
                  level = "Very Unhealthy";
                  health = "Health warnings of emergency conditions. The entire population is more likely to be affected.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid all outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit outdoor exertion.";
                  break;
              case (301 <= val):
                  level = "Hazardous";
                  health = "Health alert: everyone may experience more serious health effects";
                  sport = "Everyone should avoid all outdoor exertion";
          }

           console.log(level);
           console.log(health);
           console.log(sport);   
      });
  })
```

I can get the value using console.log but cannot get my switch statement do anything with the value.

Comment: But what are you taking from `console.log(val);`? NaN will return false for all statements

Comment: Please correct your tags. This is not angular, but angularjs question.

Comment: If `$()` is jQuery then `val` is a jQuery object, not a number. What is `val = $(things.data.current.pollution.aqius);` supposed to be doing?

Comment: In addition, remove object conversion: val = Number(things.data.current.pollution.aqius);

Comment: Is there a reason why you've used switch instead of if/else statement?

Comment: I used switch because the data that I'm getting from airvisual doesn't contain everything I need. So I need to add to it

Comment: pls publish value of val. try using parseInt to ensure val is int. also keep a default case which runs nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('GeoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = "";
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?country=usa&state=arizona&city=phoenix&key=PxJe9btQYWReyQFAm'
    }).then(function successCallback(data, status, headers,config) {
          $scope.result = data;
          var val = $scope.result.data.current.pollution.aqius;
          console.log(val);
          var level;
          var health;
          var sport;
          switch (val) {
              case (val < 50):
                  level = "Good";
                  health = "Air quality is considered satisfactory, and air pollution poses little or no risk";
                  sport = "Perfect day to play!";
                  break;
              case (51 <= val && val < 100):
                  level = "Moderate";
                  health = "Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion.";
                  break;
              case (101 <= val && val < 150):
                  level = "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups";
                  health = "Members of sensitive groups may experience health effects. The general public is not likely to be affected.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid prolonged outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion";
                  break;
              case (151 <= val && val < 200):
                  level = "Unhealthy";
                  health = "Unhealthy Everyone may begin to experience health effects; members of sensitive groups may experience more serious health effects";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid prolonged outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit prolonged outdoor exertion";
                  break;
              case (201 <= val && val < 300):
                  level = "Very Unhealthy";
                  health = "Health warnings of emergency conditions. The entire population is more likely to be affected.";
                  sport = "Active children and adults, and people with respiratory disease, such as asthma, should avoid all outdoor exertion; everyone else, especially children, should limit outdoor exertion.";
                  break;
              case (301 <= val):
                  level = "Hazardous";
                  health = "Health alert: everyone may experience more serious health effects";
                  sport = "Everyone should avoid all outdoor exertion";
          }

           console.log(level);
           console.log(health);
           console.log(sport);  
      }, function errorCallback(response) {

        console.log('data error');
      });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><body ng-app="myApp"><div ng-controller="GeoCtrl"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks unfortunately it didnt work for me. Console says Pollution is undefined

Answer (score -1):

**Updated answer:**

Looking at your code the issue is in the promise you are returning. I think you may have gotten confused on the use of data as the return type. If you look at the object that is returned from the api you get a result set of:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "city": "Phoenix",
            "state": "Arizona",
            "country": "USA",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -112.066299,
                    33.560299
                ]
            },
            "current": {
                "weather": {
                    "ts": "2017-07-17T06:00:00.000Z",
                    "tp": 25,
                    "pr": 1013,
                    "hu": 88,
                    "ws": 6,
                    "wd": 110,
                    "ic": "11n"
                },
                "pollution": {
                    "ts": "2017-07-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                    "aqius": 124,
                    "mainus": "p2",
                    "aqicn": 97,
                    "maincn": "p1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 200,
    "config": {
        "method": "GET",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "url": "http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?country=usa&state=arizona&city=phoenix&key=PxJe9btQYWReyQFAm",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        }
    },
    "statusText": "OK"
}
```

So in your code you need to change the setting of result to :

```
  $scope.result = data.data.data;
  var val = $scope.result.current.pollution.aqius;
```

This should correct the output. [Click here for a working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d2wHhaK3CzpeDRCBd1UN?p=preview)

Comment: See [Can I use switch to simplify multiple if's?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Can_I_use_switch_to_simplify_multiple_if's)